# webGL - Draw a line on a surface

Tags: 3d, webgl

I have a three dimensional textured surface that I need to draw a colored line on.  This would be similar to drawing lines of latitude/longitude on a sphere.  Is there a simple way to draw a line onto this surface?  The best result I have gotten so far is calculating points along the surface and making those my line vertices but this seems a little buggy as there are places where the line shows well and places where it doesn't.  Also, if I use this method do I need to offset the line out from the surface or do something else so that they don't "overlap" and show the surface instead of the line?

Comment: I should add too that I am not using any webGL libraries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After lots of trial and error (and time - this is very old), the best method to do this I found was to create the lines that I want on a texture and use that texture on the surface.  Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Using your current approach you need to offset the line(probably along the surface normal), the effect you see is called [z-fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) caused by the line and the surface having the same rastered depth values.

If you do not want to or can not offset the line you could render the line into a seperate framebuffer, map its texture to a fullscreen quad and blend them together.

In case you do not need to update the line you could draw it into a texture using a canvas 2D. Depending on your needs and the properties of your "surface" you may also be able to use the fragment shader to draw the line directly on the gpu.